# Recorrer todos los resultados de una API

Tags: api

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente API:

> https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms/id

Lo que me gustaría saber es si existe una manera de recorrer varios id en la consulta. Se me había ocurrido trabajar con un ciclo for, pero estoy quiero obtener esta información en la aplicación Postman

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mediante una función JS:

```
var arrayPlatforms = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var resultado = consultaAjax(i);
   if(resultado != undefined)
      arrayPlatforms.push(resultado);
}
```

Donde `arrayPlataforms` es una arreglo que tiene los datos de los resultados de cada consulta `ajax` que realices al servidor por el `id` que pasaste por parámetro.

**Aunque es poco eficiente debido a que esperaras a que el servidor responda la plataforma de `id` para agregarlo recién al arreglo final, además de que presenta el error de que no sabes a ciencia cierta si el `id` que estas enviado en verdad existe hay una mejor manera de realizarlo y te lo pongo a continuación.**

Lo mejor es que solicites la lista de plataformas completas del siguiente endpoint:

> https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms

Con eso obtienes la lista completa de plataformas en una sola llamada.

Ya queda en tus manos la posibilidad de realizar lo que gustes con la lista total, filtrarla, ordenarla, etc.

Comment: Si intente esa opción, lastimosamente no solo retorna los datos de la plataforma, si no que retorna otros datos externos, como ejemplos de juegos de la consola, algo que me gustaria evitar, ya que solo quiero la información principal de la plataforma

Comment: si retorna información adicional como `games` no importa, tú puedes usar solo la información que te es necesaria del arreglo que haz obtenido, ósea ahí tienes todo no necesitas volver a consultar, si requieres más detalle puedes hacer lo del `id` si quieres volver a crear el arreglo (hacer un doble trabajo), del arreglo de totales recorrer la lista con el `for` que te di y de su propiedad `id` de cada objeto manda la consulta Ajax.

Comment: Y para acceder solamente a la parte de los Results? Siempre que corro la petición de la API me aparecen siempre al inicio "count","next" y "previous. Despues de estos aparece "result" que es donde esta toda la información que necesito, pero no encuentro manera de ingresar solamente a esa parte de la información

Comment: @LPSoldier19 programas o solo estas experimentando con postman y las peticiones? -quieres que nos traslademos a un chat?

Comment: Si he programado, pero ahorita estoy experimentando con Postman para realizar unas peticiones para un proyecto que estoy realizando de una clase. Si te agradeceria mucho que nos trasladaramos a un chat

Comment: como podria contactarme contigo?